# How to use substring to put the date from these numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring, ssms-2012, patindex

how to pull the date (20060807) of these numbers

```
1.2.840.113782.1.3.5.8696.41870.20060807.69548508               
1.2.840.113782.1.3.1.JDI.65.1.2002816.205431857 
1.2.840.113782.1.3.1.JDI.06.8.2002816.19213160
1.2.840.113782.1.3.5.2360.28594.20030826.80612275 
1.2.840.113782.1.3.1.JDI.35.26.2002816.207943
```

Comment: Are the date formats consistent?

Comment: no, all these numbers are stored as varchar. these two have diff formats (2002816, 20030826)

Comment: basically i want to pull the information before the last dot

Comment: What about regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that the date formats are consistent.  If so, you can do:

```
select substring(col, len(col) - charindex('.', reverse(col)) - 7, 8)
```

Because the date formats are not consistent, you might end up with an extra '.' at the end.  So, get rid of it using `replace()`:

```
select replace(substring(col, len(col) - charindex('.', reverse(col)) - 7, 8), '.', '')
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/1329) is a SQL Fiddle.